# Getting C# Method With jQuery in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using the code below to display an uploaded picture in asp.net . The Image name is change to a unique name and **args.get_fileName** retrieves the original name of the file instead of the new unique name.

How can I retrieve the new unique name:

```
protected void FileUploadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh_mm_ss");
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
    AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs("~/listingImages/" + date + filename);
}
```

Script:

```
function uploadStarted() {
    $get("imgDisplay").style.display = "none";
}

function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
    var imgDisplay = $get("imgDisplay");
    imgDisplay.src = "images/loader.gif";
    imgDisplay.style.cssText = "";
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        imgDisplay.style.cssText = "height:100px;width:100px";
        imgDisplay.src = img.src;
    };

    img.src = "/listingImages/" + args.get_fileName();

    $('#bodyContent_Label1').html("/listingImages/" + args.get_fileName());
}
```

Comment: Could you just pass the filename into the view via a viewmodel?

Comment: @Canvas thank you for reply. I am new to asp.net and not sure of how i will do this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**You should use password generating concept**

```
private static string CreateRandomPassword(int passwordLength)
{
 string allowedChars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@$?_-";
 char[] chars = new char[passwordLength];
 Random rd = new Random();

 for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++)
 {
  chars[i] = allowedChars[rd.Next(0, allowedChars.Length)];
 }

 return new string(chars);
}
```

Comment: thanks, i am really new to asp.net and have no idea how to inpelment this concept with my exciting code

Comment: you know about AJAX ??

Comment: You can call CreateRandomPassword() function using AJAX and you will easily get return value as unique string

Comment: What should be lenth of my randomly generated string?

Comment: Fist of all that fellow want unique string, so we can use CreateRandomPassword Method. Than Random function will give integer number randomly so we can use **allowedChars[rd.Next(0, allowedChars.Length)];**  for creating unique string.

Comment: CreateRandomPassword(int passwordLength)